# How add command to an ElementMenuItem?

Tags: wpf, xaml, command

I am trying to add a command to an ElementMenuItem, but the command can not be fired.

```
<Grid Name="MenuGrid">
    <s:ElementMenu 
            Name="MainMenu"
            ActivationMode="AlwaysActive"
            ActivationHost="{Binding ElementName=MenuGrid}" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Menu}">
        <s:ElementMenu.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Menu}" DataType="{x:Type s:ElementMenuItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                            <behaviours:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=NavigatorMenu.SimpleCommand}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    </TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>                
        </s:ElementMenu.ItemTemplate>            
    </s:ElementMenu>
</Grid>
```

Does anyone know how to add a command to the menu? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Wth is an `ElementMenu`?

Comment: It is a Surface 2.0 SDK control item. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727728.aspx

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I have the exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what those controls are but if they inherit from normal menus you should use the `ItemContainerStyle` to hook up commands:

```
<s:ElementMenu Name="MainMenu" ActivationMode="AlwaysActive"
        ActivationHost="{Binding ElementName=MenuGrid}" ItemsSource="{Binding Menu}">
    <s:ElementMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="s:ElementMenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Command"
                    Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=NavigatorMenu.SimpleCommand}" />
        </Style>
    </s:ElementMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    <s:ElementMenu.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Menu}">
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </s:ElementMenu.ItemTemplate>
</s:ElementMenu>
```

This of course assumes that all the bindings actually work, if they don't you should probably [debug them](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx)...

Comment: @user1205398: Have you looked at the [section about command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727728.aspx#sectionSection2) in the docs?

Comment: Still not working. Seems it really can not modify the template. So in this case I have some sub-menu, how can I hierarchically export them? I don't think write them all in the xaml file is a good idea. Specially when the menu are created from the DB. Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but I find interaction triggers don't work in a Grid.  Change your xaml to

```
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Menu}" DataType="{x:Type s:ElementMenuItem}">   
            <ContentControl>
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>   
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">   
                        <behaviours:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=NavigatorMenu.SimpleCommand}"/>   
                    </i:EventTrigger>   
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>   
                <Grid>   
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}"></Image>   
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"    
                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom"    
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center">   
                    </TextBlock>   
                </Grid>   
           </ContentControl>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: Phil, 
Thanks for your reply. I have tried the method you mentioned, but still can not get the command fired.